# How can i improve this ping.js script. Seem to be getting high ping

Tags: javascript, ping

I've made this ping.js script but i seem to be getting quite a high ping even though when i ping from CMD i get a much lower ping. If there is anyway i'm able to show the true ping instead of it being much higher that would be appreciated.

```
    function colorcode(ms){
    if (ms < 65) {return "#8bc53f";
    } else if ((ms >= 65) && (ms < 160)) { return "#f26522";
    } else if ((ms >= 160) && (ms < 400)) { return "#ed1c24";
    } else if ((ms >= 400) && (ms < 1000)) { return "#ed1c24";
    } else { return "#232323"; }

}

function output_text(txt,id){
    txt = Math.round((3/4)*txt);
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var txt_ = "<font color='"+colorcode(parseInt(txt))+"'>"+((parseInt(txt)<1000)?txt+"</font> ms":"Offline</font>");
    obj.innerHTML=txt_;
}

function reping() {
i = 2;
for(var id in idips){
setTimeout("ping2('"+id+"','"+idips[id]+"',"+(i*2+1)+")",i);
i += 100;
}}

var idips = new Array();

function ping(id,ip,i){
    document.write("<span id='"+id+"'>pinging server...</span>");
    setTimeout("ping2('"+id+"','"+ip+"',"+i+")",(i+2)*100);
    idips[id] = ip;
}

function koekjes(){
var koekje = new Array('k','o','e','j','w','s');
var koek = new Array();
var rd = new Array();
var koekz = '';
var rd = new Array();
for(i=0;i<=21;i++){
rd[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*koekje.length);
koekz += koekje[rd[i]];
}
return koekz
}

function ping2(id,ip,i) {
    var ImageObject = new Image();
    ImageObject.onerror = function(evt){ var endTime = new Date(); output_text(endTime-startTime,id);}
    ImageObject.onload = function(evt){ var endTime = new Date(); output_text(endTime-startTime,id);}
    var startTime = new Date();
    ImageObject.src = "http://"+ip+"/"+koekjes()+".gif";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ping uses ICMP packets.  This script appears to time an image download over HTTP.  Those two things are completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You measure the latency between sending a request, and getting an answer.

The command line program `ping` uses an [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packet for that, you use an HTTP request.

An [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) request needs to establish a [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) connect, sending the the request (HTTP is quite chatty), parsing the request, handling the request, sending the response, and parsing the response.

But the major problem is the handshake, which makes the request three times slower.

To get the real latency you cannot use `time / 3`, because the connection could be [kept alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), in which case there is no handshake.

To summarize: don't use HTTP/TCP to measure the latency.

---

#### Edit:

You can just connect to a closed port, like 3 or 4. In this case the connection attempt (TCP syn) gets rejected by the server. (Syn is the first part in a TCP handshake.)

Online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wDz38/.

Comment: What would be the best way to get the ping from the client then as shown here: http://62.254.75.14/

Comment: @user3453512, it seems that your are interested in the best server to connect to. In this case you just need to order the list. There is no need to know the actual latency to a specific server (if I interpret your intention correctly).

Comment: But it's different for certain people depending where they live, is there a script somewhere which will achieve what i want to do or someone who knows how to make one?

Comment: Since you don't really want to download an actual file, or connect to the server, for that matter, you can just use a closed TCP port, like 4. In this case the TCP syn gets rejected, and onerror gets called. Use the line `ImageObject.src = "http://" + ip + ":3/" + koekjes() + ".gif";`. The results look sane for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wDz38/.

Comment: That makes the ms higher. I don't need the image object, that was added by accident.

Comment: "That makes the ms higher". That does not make sense. EU central for a normal port 80 request: 124ms, a request to port 3 gets rejected in 34ms. (For me, YMMV.)

Comment: Also, you should note that your connection is likely congested. Do the pinging one after another.

Comment: How can i ping it one after another?

Comment: Sorry, but you need to show some effort. Please try it yourself and open another question if you get stuck. EOD.

Comment: I didn't make this script and thank you for helping me. It means a lot.